# to.period doesn't work combined with xts format

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

Let's consider following data frame for reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Date" =
    c(
      "2009-11-02", "2009-11-03", "2009-11-04", "2009-11-05", "2009-11-06",
      "2009-11-09", "2009-11-10", "2009-11-12", "2009-11-13", "2009-11-16",
      "2009-11-17", "2009-11-18", "2009-11-19", "2009-11-20"
    ),
  "Open" = c(
    64.97971, 64.64817, 63.88567, 64.34973, 67.16770, 67.63186,
    69.48868, 68.95794, 70.08527, 72.47256,
    72.53886, 72.73724, 71.07980, 69.75345
  ),
  "High" = c(
    65.47689, 65.14544, 65.44378, 66.96887, 68.75883, 69.62065, 70.81439, 73.26807,
    71.07980, 73.13536,
    73.26807, 72.93625, 71.87532, 72.27345
  ),
  "Low" = c(
    63.98508, 62.75843, 63.71976, 64.34973, 65.47689, 66.96887, 68.36125, 68.95794,
    69.28966, 72.00803,
    72.00803, 71.14620, 69.68705, 69.75345
  ),
  "Close" = c(
    64.64817, 62.85784, 65.21174, 66.96887, 65.70910, 69.62065, 70.81439, 71.94172, 70.61537, 72.53886,
    72.80355, 71.60999, 69.68705, 70.94709
  )
)
```

This is some data frame in format OHLC (Open, High, Close, Low).

Now let's change this data frame into xts object:

```
df <- as.xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df[, 1]))
```

And now I want to apply to.period function e.g.:

```
to.period(df, period = "days", k =3)
```

I obtain error:

```
'to.period(df, period = "days", k = 3)':unsupported type
```

I read about this error and the source of it lies in the definition of `xts` object. Becuase `xts` object is a matrix every variable should have same type. The problem is here, becuase for example column "Open" is created by numeric values and first column is filled with values in date format. This is the reasoning why `as.xts()` converts everything to strings, as most common data format. However, even if I know the justification why it doens't work - I have no idea how can I made `to.period` work. Do you have any idea how it can be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the first column was not removed while constructing the `xts`

```
df <- as.xts(df[-1], order.by = as.Date(df[, 1]))
to.period(df, period = "days", k =3) 
#            df.Open  df.High   df.Low df.Close
#2009-11-03 64.97971 65.47689 62.75843 62.85784
#2009-11-06 63.88567 68.75883 63.71976 65.70910
#2009-11-09 67.63186 69.62065 66.96887 69.62065
#2009-11-12 69.48868 73.26807 68.36125 71.94172
#2009-11-13 70.08527 71.07980 69.28966 70.61537
#2009-11-18 72.47256 73.26807 71.14620 71.60999
#2009-11-20 71.07980 72.27345 69.68705 70.94709
```

---

Without removing the first column i.e.  a `character` class column ('Date'), the `xts` converts the whole data into a `character` class as it is also a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only single class

```
str(as.xts(df, order.by = as.Date(df[, 1])))
An ‘xts’ object on 2009-11-02/2009-11-20 containing:
  Data: chr [1:14, 1:5] "2009-11-02" "2009-11-03" "2009-11-04"  "2009-11-05" "2009-11-06" "2009-11-09" "2009-11-10" "2009-11-12" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Date" "Open" "High" "Low" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```